# Aliasing a closure type in Rust, but compiler asks for lifetime specifier

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm a completely newbie to Rust or even to these languages that touches bare metal.

I was going to alias a closure type that takes a few pointers as arguments, and returns a String. With the newest syntax (if I understood correctly) I wrote:

```
pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
```

And the compiler requires me to add lifetime specifier for every pointer argument:

```
src/helpers.rs:24:26: 24:49 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/helpers.rs:24:43: 24:48 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                                            ^~~~~
src/helpers.rs:24:44: 24:48 error: explicit lifetime bound required
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                                             ^~~~
src/helpers.rs:24:51: 24:58 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                                                    ^~~~~~~
src/helpers.rs:24:60: 24:69 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~
src/helpers.rs:24:61: 24:69 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                                                              ^~~~~~~~
src/helpers.rs:24:71: 24:89 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/helpers.rs:24:76: 24:89 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/helpers.rs:24:22: 24:99 error: explicit lifetime bound required
src/helpers.rs:24 pub type HelperDef = Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>;
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 9 previous errors
```

I should say I'm completely confused for the lifetime specifiers here. I can achieve the same functionality by defining a custom trait with this function only, and the compiler doesn't ask for a lifetime about these pointers in that way. But I think using a shared closure should be more beautiful from API level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the global level, there is no type inference; all things must be written out explicitly, with the exception of lifetime elision rules for function definitions (that is, how you can write things like `fn x(&self) -> &Foo` rather than needing to write `fn x<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Foo`).

This is significant in this case because `Fn<(&HashMap<String, &Show>, &Helper, &Registry, &mut RenderContext), String>` *is not a complete concrete type*. There are two problems with it:

1. `Fn` is a *trait*, not a concrete type; you would need to either box your unboxed closure (`Box<Fn<…, …>>`, which can incidentally be written `Box<Fn(…) -> …>`) or go for generics everywhere where necessary;
2. You’re lacking plenty of lifetimes.

Ignoring the first point, let’s just worry about the second. What you would *actually* need to write is something along these lines:

```
pub type HelperDef<'a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'g, 'h> =
    Fn(&'a HashMap<String, &'b Show>, &'c Helper, &'d Registry<'e>,
       &'f mut RenderContext<'g>) -> String + 'h;
```

Most of those should make sense, but the `'h` one and the `+ 'h` may not so much: that one is because `Fn` is a trait; to form an alias for the trait (which will be an unsized type—dynamically sized types are a long story I won’t attempt to explain here), that lifetime bound must be made explicit (that is the subject of the very last of the errors).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, it's very helpful to me. I need some time to fully understand this. Taking 8 specifiers everywhere could be a nightmare, perhaps I should switch back to the trait based design.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use higher-ranked lifetimes here? `pub type HelperDef<'a> = for<'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'g, 'h> Fn(&'b HashMap<String, &'c Show>, &'d Helper, &'e Registry<'f>, &'g mut RenderContext<'h>) -> String + 'a;`

Comment: @FrancisGagné: I haven’t come across that before—what does it actually mean in practice?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: See [RFC 387](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0387-higher-ranked-trait-bounds.md).